# Grouping together same exponent terms in a multivariate monomial

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

This is a rather simple question but for some reason, I am spending too much time on this.

Suppose I have a monomial in 4 variables, each raised to some linear combination of 3 exponent variables: `{a1, a2, a3, a4}`, and `{b1, b2, b3}`.

Now I want to collect monomial subexpressions with the same exponent variable together. For eg, if I have the following input:

```
(-a1)^(b1 + 2b2 + b3) a2^(-b2 + b3) (-a3)^(-2b1 + b2) a4^(3b1 + 4b3)
```

I should obtain precisely the following expression as output:

```
(-1)^(-b1 + 3b2 + b3) ((a1 a4^3)/a3^2)^b1 ((a1^2 a3)/a2)^b2 (a1 a2 a4^4)^b3
```

Note: it would be better if the solution to this query doesn't involve the use of `ReplaceRepeated`, and that it works for the full general case of $m$ monomial variables `{a1, a2, ..., am}` with $n$ exponent variables `{b1, b2, ...,  bn}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
expr = (-a1)^(b1 + 2 b2 + b3) a2^(-b2 + b3) (-a3)^(-2 b1 + b2) a4^(3 b1 + 4 b3);
```

You can reorganize the output from a composition of [`FactorList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorList.html) and [`PowerExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html)  into the desired form using [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) + [`KeyValueMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValueMap.html):

```
FactorList @ PowerExpand @ expr
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1}, {(-1)^b3, 1}, {(-1)^b2, 3}, {(-1)^b1, -1}, 
>   {a1^b3, 1}, {a1^b2, 2}, {a1^b1, 1}, 
>   {a2^b3, 1}, {a2^b2, -1}, {a3^b2, 1}, {a3^b1, -2},
>   {a4^b3, 4}, {a4^b1, 3}}
> ```

```
ClearAll[kvm, groupByExponents]

kvm = KeyValueMap[If[#, 
   Times @@ Power @@@ #2, 
   KeyValueMap[(Times @@ #2)^# &] @ 
      GroupBy[#2, #[[1, 2]] &, Map[#[[1, 1]]^#[[2]] &]]] &];

groupByExponents[exp_] := Module[{fl = FactorList @ PowerExpand @ exp}, 
  Times @@ Prepend[Power @@ First[fl]] @
    Flatten[kvm @ GroupBy[Rest @ fl, NumericQ @ #[[1, 1]] &]]]

groupByExponents @ expr
```

[image]